# Does Magento have a default category ID for all "New" products regardless of main category?

Tags: products-management

I would like to have a "New" products carousel on my home page.  I've got them for other items in specific categories but I would like one that lists all items that are new regardless of category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Magento Will not Provide you the Default Category ID for new category product.

1) you can do one thing create the new category like `slider`.

2) When you create new products then assign that product to that category as well as your normal category.

3) At Home page just load the category and make slider as per your requirement.

Comment: What does Magento do with the field that asks "Set Product as New from Date?"  Is that a category or callable item?

Comment: for this magento call one new.phtml file and you have to do add manually on home page cms .

Comment: when you select the date so this product will display only matched product on home page

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/adding-new-products-list-to-home-page

Comment: refer this link so you got proper Idea.